# Creating directive causes [ng:areq] error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular project, app.js and then main.js for the controller. Thing is I want to create a directive, and I get 2 different errors whether I create it at app.js or main.js, but not working either way.

This is my app.js (no directive yet)

```
var myapp = angular
  .module('nombre_proyectoApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngDialog'
  ]);

  myapp.config(function ($routeProvider,$sceDelegateProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        //templateUrl: '/dms/static/nombre_proyecto/views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        //templateUrl: '/dms/static/nombre_proyecto/views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self','http://*.leroymerlin.es/**']);

  });
```

And this is my main.js (no directive yet)

```
myapp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http','ngDialog','$sce', function ($scope, $http, ngDialog, $sce) {

    $scope.Math = window.Math;

    $scope.seleccion = 'all';

    $scope.productos = [];

    $http.get('productos.json').then(function(response){
      $scope.productos = response.data;                
    });

    $scope.select = function (s){
      $scope.seleccion = s;
    };

  }]);
```

Now, this works just fine, but when i add the directive in main.js like this

```
myapp.directive('listado', function(){

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(element, attrs){
        var filtro = attrs.filtro || 'all';
        var productos = attrs.productos;
        var htmlText = '
          <ul>
            <li class="producto col-md-12" ng-repeat="producto in '+ productos +'" ng-if="(producto.group == '+ filtro +') || ('+ filtro +' == \'all\')">

              <div class="col-md-4">
               <img src="{{producto.imgUrl}}" alt="foto">
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-5">
               <p class="titulo">{{producto.title}}</p>
               <p class="verdeLM"><a href="http://www.leroymerlin.es/fp/{{producto.ref}}">Ref. {{producto.ref}}</a></p>
               <p class="gris">{{producto.description}}</p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
               <div class="precio">{{Math.floor(producto.price)}},<sup>{{decimales(producto.price)}} &euro;</sup></div>
               <a class="btnVerProd" href="http://www.leroymerlin.es/fp/{{producto.ref}}" target="_blank" ng-click="verProd(producto.ref)">Ver producto</a>
              </div>

            </li>
          </ul>';
        element.replaceWith(htmlText);
      }
    };

  });
```

Then I get this error:

**angular.js:13424 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined**

So, I try to put in app.js, and then I get this other error:

**angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module nombre_proyectoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'nombre_proyectoApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=nombre_proyectoApp**

In main.html I'm calling directive like this

```
<listado productos="productos"></listado>
```

Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed... On top of every error, I had an illegal token making everything go wrong.